# Is there there any difference or reason to prefer one of these function signatures?

Tags: scala, types, type-signature

I don't think there's any difference, or reason to prefer one over the other, but wanted to check...

```
def length(l: List[Any])
def length[T](l: List[T])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the length of any `List`, there is no difference for you. 

But if you want operatations with the elements of that list, there is.

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
def secondElementAny(l: List[Any]) = l.tail.head
def secondElementGen[A](l : List[A]) = l.tail.head
```

Giving those two functions and the list, we will expect to get the `2` from the `List`.

```
val secondAny = secondElementAny(l)
val secondGen = secondElementGen(l)
```

If we would print the values to the console, we could spot no diference, but if we try to cast them to `Float` for example, we will get an error. `secondAny.toFloat` will tell us, that secondAny is type of `Any` and that we cannot use the function `toFloat` on `Any`.

In contrast `secondGen.toFloat` will give us a `Float` value.

The reason for that is, that the compiler aproximates the full signatures as follows.

```
def secondElementAny(l: List[Any]): Any = l.tail.head
def secondElementGen[A](l: List[A]): A = l.tail.head
```

As you can see the return type of the first function is `Any`, so we will always get an `Any` whereas the return type of the second function depends on the type of the `List`. We will get an element of that type. This is typesafe.

Answer (score 6):

You could also write it like this:

```
def length(l: List[_])
```

Now, with regards to your question, `List[Any]` will, indeed accept any `List`, but if you had tried `Set[Any]`, it would not work! For instance, try passing a `Set[Int]` to it:

```
scala> def length(s: Set[Any]) = s.size
length: (s: Set[Any])Int

scala> val set = Set(1, 2, 3)
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

scala> length(set)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
 required: Set[Any]
Note: Int <: Any, but trait Set is invariant in type A.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
              length(set)
                     ^
```

`List` is co-variant, which makes that possible, but not every parameterized class is covariant. Either your parameterized version or the version above will work, though.

I can't think of any reason to prefer one over the other, but I'd rather not parameterize something when it is not needed. If nothing else, it will have a slight positive impact on compilation speed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference:

```
def head_1(l: List[Any]) = {
  l.head
}

def head_2[T](l: List[T]) = {
  l.head
}

// Doesn't compile, head_1 returns Any
// head_1(List(1,2,3)) > 1

head_2(List(1,2,3)) > 1                   //> res0: Boolean = false
```

Comment: By providing those particular method bodies, though, you've changed the signature from what was in the question.

Comment: @ChristopherMartin It does answer my question by giving a reason to prefer one to the other in certain circumstances (i.e. the code wouldn't compile!)

Comment: head_1 does compile. It returns an Any that is correct, but it compiles.

Comment: @TGrottker `> 1` doesn't compile as `Any` doesn't have method `>`